# What is meant by "pensée indétérminée" in the Geneva School?

Tags: french-language, literary-criticism

When I was learning about the Geneva School critics, my tutor said that Georges Poulet and other Geneva School critics wanted to remove the biographical author although he still survives as an indeterminate thought (pensée indétérminée). I don't really know what that means and I can't find much information about it, so can someone please explain that term to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the foreword ("Avant-propos") to *La pensée indeterminée I. De la Renaissance au romantisme*, the Belgian critic [Georges Poulet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges_Poulet) describes the goal of his three-volume work (emphasis mine):

> L'ensemble de petites études que voici, consacrée à une assez longue série de penseurs et de poètes depuis l'avènement du christianisme jusqu'à nos jours, vise à mettre en valeur dans toutes ces pensées une inflexion négative, souvent presque imperceptible, mais extraordinairement efficace. Elle tend à montrer que, derrière les déterminations particulières, se dissimule **quelque chose qui n'a pas de nom et qui est presque inexprimable. C'es la pensée indéterminée**. On la reconnaît, parfois facilement, par exemple dans la rêverie. Mais son domaine est infiniment plus vaste, et ne se contente pas d'abriter simplement les idées vagues, les sentiments indistincts, si fréquents dans une certaine poésie. A l'autre extrémité de la pensée indéterminée, il y a le silence intérieur, la prise de connaissance d'un moi indépendant et l'impression d'un pouvoir illimité, tenu en suspens, en attendant qu'il nous pousse dans telle direction ou dans telle autre. C'est ce suspens qui importe. Il jou un rôle inappréciablement important en retardant le moment inévitable où la pensée s'engagera, bon gré mal gré, à fonds perdu, en direction de quelque objet déterminé.

Translation:

> The collection of short studies presented here, devoted to a rather long series of thinkers and poets from the advent of christianity to the present day, aims to highlight in all these thoughts a negative shift, often almost imperceptible but extraordinarily effective. These studies tends to show that, behind the specific determination **something is hiding which has no name and which is almost inexpressible. This is the indeterminate thought**. One can sometimes easily recognise it, for example in daydreams / reveries. But its realm is infinitely more vast and does not satisfy itself with simply sheltering the vague ideas or indistinct sentiments that are so common in a certain kind of poetry. On the other extreme of indeterminate thought, there is the inner silence, the realisation of a independent "I" and the impression of limitless power, kept in suspense and waiting until it pushes us in a certain direction. It is this suspense / being on hold that counts. It plays an incredibly important role by delaying the inevitable moment when thought commits itself, willingly or unwillingly, towards some determinate object.

Indeterminate thought thus contrasts with determinate thoughts or explicit ideas, which are what history of literature usually discusses. According to Poulet, indeterminate thought is not limited to a few rare works but is present almost everywhere, behind the more obvious explicit thoughts.